# Return key action UITextView Swift

Tags: textview, return, action

I'm surprised I was unable to find a solution to this issue.

When using a different return key type in a textview (something other than 'Return'), there seems to be no methods for handling pressing these buttons for a textview.

For example if I set:

```
textView.returnKeyType = .Go
```

There is no TextView delegate method that handles pressing 'Go'.

It appears the only way to even handle pressing the 'Return' key is by using:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
     if (text == "\n") {
         //action here
         return false
     }
     return true
}
```

Although this suffices for the return key, it doesn't work for other return key actions. Additionally, this seems like a crude way to handle return presses.

Comment: use textField for this

Comment: I was going to but I need to handle multiple lines of input. I suppose I could make a custom textfield with embedded view but there seems like there should be a way to handle other return button presses. Why would they include the ability to use different return button types if you couldn't set actions for them.